# JavaScript: Dynamically detect media type of iframe contents (if it's video/gif or static image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to dynamically replace iframes with either video or image they contain.

Cross-domain requests are restricted, but every `<iframe>` has `src` attribute, so it's possible to generate a direct link to a file without a particular file extension. Then we should detect media type of each file. I tried to complete this task with the code below, but it doesn't work as expected (sometimes it kinda works, but treats all the files as images (even videos):

```
        if($('video').length > 0) {
            iframe[i].parentNode.replaceChild(video, iframe[i]);
        } else if (image.complete) {
            iframe[i].parentNode.replaceChild(image, iframe[i]);
          } else {
            iframe[i].parentNode.replaceChild(link, iframe[i]);
          }
```

I also tried `video.readyState > 0` for videos and `image.naturalWidth !== 0` for images, but without success.

**JSFiddle example with the complete code:** https://jsfiddle.net/52st2foj/

Is this even possible with only JavaScript (and maybe jQuery)? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry, can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do? It's  not clear what the code sample you posted is trying to accomplish, given that `$('video')` called from the top window won't (and usually can't) search anything within an iframe.

Comment: @furkle, JSFiddle contains the complete code. I'll add it to my post then.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that! I must still be asleep. I'll take a look at it.